# conflict between Jquery slider html5 animation and cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle, adobe-edge

is the header html5 sometimes works and sometimes not at one glance with the cycle slider. Both use Jquery and I think there must be a mistake. In Chrome console gives me the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'okToLaunchComposition' head_edgePreload.js:5
edgeCallback head_edgePreload.js:5
(anonymous function)                          head_edgePreload.js:2
t                                             head_edgePreload.js:2
d                                             head_edgePreload.js:2
I.b.onreadystatechange.b.onload               head_edgePreload.js:2
I                                             head_edgePreload.js:2
(anonymous function)
```

Here you have the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>BLOG</title> 
<script src="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/galeria/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/estilo-pagina-css.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/galeria/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script> 

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#slider1').cycle({
        fx: 'fade', //'scrollLeft,scrollDown,scrollRight,scrollUp',blindX, blindY, blindZ, cover, curtainX, curtainY, fade, fadeZoom, growX, growY, none, scrollUp,scrollDown,scrollLeft,scrollRight,scrollHorz,scrollVert,shuffle,slideX,slideY,toss,turnUp,turnDown,turnLeft,turnRight,uncover,ipe ,zoom
        speed:  '600', 
        timeout: '700000000',
        next:   '#next', 
        prev:   '#prev',
        pager:  '#thumb',
           pauseOnHover: true,              // if you hover pauses the slider
            startClockOnMouseOut: true,         // if clock should start on MouseOut
             manualAdvance: true,


        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
            return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="43" height="29" /></a></li>'; 
        }  
    });

});



</script>
<script language="javascript">
/**
 * Adobe Edge DOM Ready Event Handler
 */
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(window).ready(function() {
     jQuery.Edge.initialize(symbols);
});
/**
 * Adobe Edge Timeline Launch
 */
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery.Edge.play();
});

</script>
<style type="text/css">

#contenedor {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
}
</style>
<link href="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/galeria/estilo-galeria.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="contenedor">
<div id="cabecera" >
 <object id="EdgeID" type="text/html" width="900" height="167" data-dw-widget="Edge" data="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/head/Assets/head.html">
  </object>
</div>
<div id="botonera"><?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/botonera.php"); ?></div>
<div id="sombra-galeria-botonera"><?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/galeria/botonera-galeria.php"); ?></div>
<div id="para-contenido"></div>
<div id="centro_galeria"><?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/galeria/includes/piragua.php"); ?>
</div>
<div id="para-contenido2"><?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/galeria/presentacion-galeria.php"); ?></div>
<div id="separador"><img src="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>/imagenes-blog/separador.png" /></div>

<div id="sha-do">
</div>
<div id="pie"><?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/pie.php"); ?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The page example:

http://bolivar.uphero.com/

Comment: Please use English language only.

Comment: Sorry, I edit. Thanks

Comment: Could you reproduce the situation in jsFiddle?

Comment: Sorry but you can not. But you can see here, the top black slot is where the animation should appear html5 adobe edge but does not appear.    http://bolivar.uphero.com/